# ¿Alguien que me oriente de por que no me deja compartir los datos de el producto como: imagen, descripción y titulo uso AddThis?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Saludos estoy usando [addthis](https://www.addthis.com/) y no me deja compartir la imagen del producto de forma dinámica, he leído la documentación y agregue los atributos al botón, pero a la ora de compartir el producto el botón de addthis no me toma la imagen ni la descripción de el producto que quiero compartir  solo me imprime el titulo del producto, los datos del producto los imprimo con PHP las variables i traen los datos ya que las utilizo antes de el proceso, lo único que hace es tomar los datos de las meta tags de la pagina y no los datos del producto que quiero compartir

Este es el fragmento de código del botón

```
<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox" data-title = "<?=$oneProduct->prod_nombre;?>" data-description = "Producto comestible" data-media = "<?=base_url;?>adm/uploads/images_product/122_taco_principal/taco_principal.1605854694.png"></div>
```

Espero me puedan orientar un saludo

Comment: tendra algo que ver con los espacios:  data-media = "

Comment: Revisa la consola, seguramente hay errores ahí. La web oficial tiene errores y no funciona, al menos en Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de hacer login en tu cuenta, asegurate de seguir todos los pasos descritos en la liga de abajo, se ve que esta facil

- estas añadiendo el javascript al final de la pagina en html?

https://www.addthis.com/dashboard?from=register#gallery/pub/ra-60041f6790bbb560/get-the-code-from-tool/pco/ist/widgetId/88nm